# jQuery("body").undelegate is not a function error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a form that works perfectly. Now, when i add the following code, it throws the ***jQuery("body").undelegate is not a function*** error.

```
            <?php
            echo CHtml::dropDownList(
                            'country_id',
                            '',
            array('0'=>'Choice One',
                            '1'=>'USA',
                            '2'=>'France',
                        '3'=>'Japan',),
            array(
                      'ajax'=>array(
                          'type'=>'POST',
                          'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('users/aTest'),
                          'success'=>'function(data){alert(data)}',
            )));
            ?>
```

In UsersController, I have the following action (and it is also included in the accessRules)

```
    public function actionATest()
    {
        echo "this is a test";
    }
```

When i expand the error, a specific line of code is highlighted (the second one)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".errorDisplay").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000).fadeOut("slow");
   jQuery('body').undelegate('#country_id','change').delegate('#country_id','change',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','url':'/index.php/users/unaPrueba','success':function(data){alert(data)},'cache':false,'data':jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()});return false;});
```

Any ideas??? Anybody had this problem? Couldn't find it anywhere!

Comment: Why are you using undelegate and then delegate again?

Comment: Why are you using delegate with an ID element? Why are you using delegate on `<body>`, why not use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead?

Comment: An obvious question, but I'll ask it anyway: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Trevor and @Dominic Barnes I am not using delegate and then undelegate.. I mean, what i wrote with the Yii framework (the Chtml::dropdownlist) rendered that code, with the undelegate & delegate.

Comment: @Anthony Grist I am using v1.6.2

Comment: Your code seems fine, it must be a problem with jQuery loading or conflicting. View your rendered source to see if it's being included properly and only once. Also, try typing `jQuery('#country_id')` into Firebug console and see if it returns the select object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your jQuery includes aren't conflicting. If you're adding jQuery with your own  tag, Yii might still be automatically adding another jQuery file you weren't expecting, as part of its built-in assets ([see this question](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/3898-jquery-and-assets-folder-questions/)). You can disable Yii's jQuery:

```
'components'=>array(
    'clientScript'=>array(
         'scriptMap'=>array(
              'jquery.js'=>false,
         ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I had forgotten all about this question, i solved it a long time ago and this was exactly the source of the problem so i'm marking your answer as the correct one. I was including different versions of jQuery from different places. Once i solved this, the error went away.